# How to lock a file on remote machine?

Tags: java, multithreading, shell, file-locking, filelock

I need to read and write serveral files in serveral remote machines. Mainly using java, and shell is also ok.

At first, I want to ssh to the remote machine and read/write file, and using `Channel.lock()` to lock the file. But I found it difficult to implement...

Then, I have another way:

For every remote file, such as FileA, provide a shell script, such as changFileA.sh on the remote machine in advance.

Thus, I can concurrent execute the tasks. Each task contained the following info.

```
machineIp, filePath, changeScriptPath, changeParam
```

But the question is that, there will be more than one task to modify the same file at the same time.

How I can lock it? Only allow one thread to modify the same file?

Thank you.

Comment: The linked question is about implementing file locking from shell scripts.  You clearly already know how to run a shell script remotely (using ssh), and how to run an external command from Java.  So you should be able to put all 3 things together.

Comment: Thus, I must lock the file in shell script, at first, I wanted to lock the file in java programs. Both are OK.

Comment: It depends on what you are locking against.  The semantics of `FileLock` are platform specific.  Read the javadocs carefully.  Note also that `FileLock` is NOT suitable for a use-case where two threads in the same JVM are locking against each other.  (Again, read the javadoc.)